# Django logging on html page?

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7, logging

Totally new to python..please go easy!! :)

So i am working on django 1.7.7 and in models page(`.py` files) i am able to successfully log the required details but the final page which renders in HTML i am stumped.

Can someone please tell me how to log values in django MVC on HTML page.

I tried using it as below :

```
{% from common.logger import Logger as _Logger %}
{% logger = _Logger('someapp', logger='someappLogger') %}
{% logger_stats.info("someapp marker here") %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <!-- whole markup with dynamic python values -->
</html>
```

PS : I'll admit this fact that m not sure if i am asking the question using right terminology...feel free to correct me!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. This isn't even nearly valid template syntax. What are you hoping to do? What do you want to log and where, and why can't you do it in the view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : wow...so many questions..ok, i'll try answering it....so i have some operations happening in views and it generates an `id` and i am logging it there but then after successful redirect (*on the html page*), i am trying to check if the same `id` is getting processed on my `html` page or not OR if at all html page is working or not because many users are complaining of just seeing a blank page....do i make sense now? :)

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. You don't do redirects on the template either. All of this should be done in the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I am doing all this(*operations*) in `views.py` and doing a redirect from there to my `html` page and there rises my question of verifying the `id` of `views.py` on my html page.... now, any sense?? :)

Comment: Sorry, really not. Redirecting is when you send the user from one URL to another. You don't redirect to an HTML page, you render a template in your view; and the view is where you should be doing the logging. I think you need to post the codee if that view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug a template and not python code, it is usually trickier.

Have a look at 
https://github.com/calebsmith/django-template-debug
(haven't tried it but it looks like what you need)

Answer (score 0):

First, within Django template, pure python is not supported in template tags (between `{%` and `%}`). It has its own [syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/).

If you want to log something onto the page, put the log string into a variable, and pass it to the template through context:

```
# In the view function
return render(request, "text.html", context={"logstr": log_str})
# In the template
<p>{{logstr}}</p>
```

But I don't think you should print debug information directly on the page, which is messy. Consider using [Django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/index.html), it has a logging plugin that can satisfy your need.

Comment: The link to Django-debug-toolbar results in a 404 error. The correct address ist https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/